# Structuring text over image in header

Tags: html, css

I'm quite a newbie at HTML/CSS and I'm starting a project during the summer to learn some more web programming. The website is mostly going to contain information I use/need fast access too. So thinking about including links to all school, work etc -related stuff.

I've just started so sorry if this is trivial for you guys! I tried to find solutions for the problem I have but didn't really find a solution.

The header I had in mind have this structure:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVcLx.png)

I've fixed the navbar already but I keep having issues with the header-part.
Here is the code I have right now: https://jsfiddle.net/pefypr7v/2/

```css
html,body { 
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header > *:not(.background-img) {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.background-img > h2 {
    margin-top:0; 
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}

.background-img {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6l22Aq.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="background-img">
        <h2> Random title</h2>
    </div>
    
</header>
```

The problems I'm having:

- Grey text-background only cover the text and a bit transparent (Any way to select color with color-code [i.e FFFFFF] and transparency instead of rgba(x,x,x,x)?)
- Title to be vertically aligned in middle

Comment: I tried solving the alignment-issue by adding "height: 50%;" but that made the text-background cover half the image.

Nvm about the color-issue, found it...

Comment: h2 {
 
  text-align: center;
  background:#FFF!important;
  display:inline;
   opacity: 0.5;
  
} IS it what you require >

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. About the opacity; I only want it for the text-background and not the text, is that possible?

Comment: the problem with opacity: 0.5 is that it is applied to the whole container and not only on the background-color. so the text will also have only 0.5 opacity, when it is a child of the background-img container. you can use rgba(#FFFFF, 0.5);  within css-preprocessors like LESS, SASS or Stylus. those will translate it for you to the rgba pattern. but the browser expects the rgba-pattern like so:  rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)

Comment: @CodingPadawan - it will set text-background .

Answer (score 0):

update following css part

working fiddle

**[fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/pefypr7v/8/)**

```
.background-img>h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header>*:not(.background-img) {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.background-img>h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.background-img {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6l22Aq.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="background-img">
    <h2> Random title</h2>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Oh cool! Looks great, but the I meant the title to be vertically aligned in the center, you can check my imgur-link!

And do you know if there's a way to add the opacity in the color hex code? If I have #ffc9c5, how do I had opacity?

Comment: You can use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`  approach to get opacity

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for vertical Aligning ([Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pefypr7v/4/)):

```
html,body { 
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header > *:not(.background-img) {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.background-img > h2 {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.background-img {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6l22Aq.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
  position: relative
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

For the opacity you could use Hex Codes and use the CSS Property `opacity` ([Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pefypr7v/7/)):

```
.myclass{
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #341234;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the answer of [Lokesh Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6299600/lokesh-gupta), since it was only missing the vertical align. You can achive this via:

```
.background-img > h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header>*:not(.background-img) {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.background-img {
  text-align: center;
}

.background-img > h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.background-img {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6l22Aq.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="background-img">
    <h2> Random title</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i am not getting question but i saw your images as per you want to make "https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVcLx.png" so make this type of html. 
hope it useful for you.

```css
html,body { 
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
.warrper {border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:auto; float:left; margin:0px; padding:20px 0px;
}
header {
 width: 100%;  height: auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative; text-transform: uppercase;  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/N6l22Aq.jpg') repeat left top;
 }
 /*IF YOU WANT BACKGROUND COLOR BEHIND OF HEADER TITLE THAN USE THIS CLASS*/
header h2 {background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); font-size:24px; color:#fff; float:left; padding:10px 20px;
} 
 
nav {border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:auto; float:left; margin:0px; padding:20px 0px}
nav ul {width:100%; height:auto; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
nav ul li {float:left; margin:0px; padding:0px;list-style-type:none;}
nav ul li a {margin:0px; padding:10px 20px; font-size:17px; color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<div class="warrper">
<header>
  <h2> Random title</h2>
  <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" titile="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" titile="Home">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" titile="Home">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" titile="Home">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav> 
</header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the heading tag and make a custom style
like

```
<header>
    <div class="background-img">
         Random title
    </div>

</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anandnaha/znwc5s6f/

Answer (score 0):

for easy translation of your hex-code you could use the chrome-dev-tools like shown in the images:

[image: click on a color item]

[image: change the color code and click on the marked arrows]

[image: get the rgba-color code]